# Dell Vostro 2520 has flickering green line to top of screen after running system update

Tags: wireless, screen, dell-vostro

I have 4 Vostros2520 that came with Ubuntu 11.10 64bit and they were all fine until I ran the system update.  After the system update was completed a green flickering line appeared to the top of the screen of all the laptops.  This appear to be a driver issue with the updates.  I tried changing the OS on one of the laptops to Ubuntu 12.10 and ran the updates.  The monitor worked fine but now the Boardcom device 4365 wireless card is not showing. Therefore I have solved 1 problem and fall into another.  I don't know if to revert back to Ubuntu version 11.10 and just never run updates.  Or try and get the wireless card to work under version 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu version 11.10 and after install only the updates and drivers that you need.

Comment: A re-install should not be the first option here.  The solution would require finding out what module was installed that caused the problem, and reverting to the previous known working one or an alternative replacement.